# HTML with CSS: How to style font in a table?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML code:

```
<table class="hometable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

with CSS:

```
table.hometable {
  border-spacing: 2px 2px;
  border-collapse: separate; 
  width: 100%;
}

table.hometable td {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

How can I underline the word `fox`?

Comment: you can wrap fox in <u></u>.

Comment: That's not the proper usage of a `u` element - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way with pure CSS, but you can wrap fox in `span` element, for example, and style it with `text-decoration: underline`.

```css
table.hometable {
  border-spacing: 2px 2px;
  border-collapse: separate; 
  width: 100%;
}

table.hometable td {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 2px;
}

table.hometable span {text-decoration: underline}
```

```html
<table class="hometable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>The quick brown <span>fox</span> jumps over the lazy dog.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this affect all `spans`? How do I limit it to `table.hometable` `span`?

Comment: @Danijel: Yes, it does, but you can change the rule to be applied only for `span`s inside `table.hometable`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

give it a `span` and apply a `border-bottom` or a `text-decoration:underline`:

```css
table.hometable {
  border-spacing: 2px 2px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 100%;
}
table.hometable td {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 2px;
}
.one span {
  border-bottom: 1px red solid
}
.two span {
  text-decoration: underline red
}
```

```html
<table class="hometable one">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>The quick brown <span>fox</span> jumps over the lazy dog.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="hometable two">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>The quick brown <span>fox</span> jumps over the lazy dog.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```